# Python Pip install

Tags: python-3.10

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\nelvine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

[that is the error coming up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl0pA.png) 
what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's just a Warning, not an Error, I don't understand your problem, just read the Warning?

Comment: I believe @EddyWes is referring to the linked screenshot